# What is the explanation for the ending of "Mallory's Oracle"?

Tags: carol-oconnell, mallorys-oracle

At the end of *Mallory's Oracle* by Carol O'Connell, Charles seems to

> get shot twice in the heart at pointblank range or something

and then in the next scene he is

> in hospital but awake and fine.

Is there an explanation for this anywhere or is it just a literary miracle?